# Save Form Field Value and Triggering script

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

What would be the easiest way to save a specific form field value id `#order_id` on a browser cookie on submit of the form and then when the visitor visits a certain page bring the value back to execute a script

```
fbq('track', 'Purchase', 
{currency: "USD", value: 30.00, order_id: "cookievaluefororder_id"});
```

Comment: localStorage or sessionStorage or save in session on server. Cookies are not needed here

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to comments above solved it by using localstorage

on form page:

```
var dnidelpedido = $("#541001873").val();
localStorage.setItem('order_id', dnidelpedido);
```

on thank you page after confirmed puchase:

```
var orderid = localStorage.getItem('order_id');
fbq('track', 'Purchase', {value: 915.00, currency: 'ARS', order_id: orderid});
```